# Is blender suitable for motorcycle crash simulation? (Semi-scientific)

Tags: physics

I’m a long time 3d animator (20 years using 3d studio, Max, Maya). However, I’m retired from CGI work and now I’m MacBook Pro 2019 based. So my software options are limited to Blender or Houdini.

I’m working on an article and video about motorcycle crashes and motorcycle clothing impact protection. It’d be nice to create visualizations which would be fairly scientific. I’ve got a few days using blender and it seems ok. I’d like to be able to display statistics in real-time (velocity, forces, etc)

Any plugins, advice, thoughts on blender’s suitability.

Comment: I don't think that blender is the right tool for scientific accuracy. Keep in mind that blender is mostly aimed at video work and gaming asset creation.

Comment: Is the kind of crash shown here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WSZ8AExo2sk what you are looking for?